# following header on page scroll not following

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

i am trying to have the tipical menu following the webpage scroll,

i wanted to change the position relating the marginTop with the page scroll,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var v= $(document).scrollTop();
        console.log(v);
        if(v>50){
            $('.menu').css({'marinTop':v+'px'});
            console.log(true);
        }else{
            $('.menu').css('marginTop','50px');                        
            console.log(false);
        }
    });
});
```

but it just wont move the bar... :s

Comment: You have an extra parenthese here: `function()({`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var value = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(value>+$('.menu').css('marginTop').replace(/px$/, "")) {
            $('.menu').css({'position':'fixed','top': 0});
        }else{
            $('.menu').css('position','static');                        
        }
    });
});
```

Fixed 2 things:

- Removed the `".px"` (`css("marginTop")` returns `"50px"`, which can not be compared to a number)
- You should really use "`position: fixed`" instead of a javascript-updated "`position: absolute`"

Comment: i think i will use this aproach, at the end. so the item can be anywhere http://jsfiddle.net/8zLuz/43/